# input file with two conditions

Tags: php, mysql

I have 5 input fields,after uploading images i will take all the values and store the names in one column(using implode). when i want to edit the form,if i edit only one input leaving others same in the column. How to do it??

```
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
$tmp_name = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"][$i];
if($tmp_name != null){
  $img = 'g'.$random.$_FILES["photo"]["name"][$i]; // image name thats going to save in db and folder.
move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$folder.$img);
$images_name =$images_name."~~".$img;   
    $imageup=mysql_query("update pg_details set gallery='$images_name' where id='$id'");
}
}
```

The above code works for the input with upload and when i want to update i want other names remain same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're solely updating the images, then it'll be done like this. Also, you were sending an SQL query to update the database at every loop. Do it when the loop is finished.

```
//fetch the existing images first
$imagedown = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT gallery FROM pg_details WHERE `id`='".$id."'"));
$images = explode("~~", $imagedown['gallery']);

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++){
    $tmp_name = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"][$i];
    if($tmp_name != null){
      $img = 'g'.$random.$_FILES["photo"]["name"][$i]; // image name thats going to save in db and folder.
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name,$folder.$img);
    //replace the respective index with the image it's to be replaced with

    if(isset($images[$i])){
        $images[$i] = $img;
    }else{
       array_push($images, $img);
    }
}
    $images_name = implode("~~", $images);
    //$images_name =$images_name."~~".$img;   
    $imageup=mysql_query("update pg_details set gallery='$images_name' where id='$id'");
```